# Search for expression in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have data.table with data that looks like this:

```
 9:                                                   FIXED ASSETS
10:                c("Tangible assets", "2", "726,809", "729,029")
11:                c("Investments", "3", "2,020,888", "2,020,888")
```

I would like to extract the whole row of the data.table given the searching parameter:

```
search <- quote(ColName=="Tangible assets")
WholeRow <- subset(DT, eval(search))
```

or else, I have tried this:

```
DT[ColName=="Tangible assets"]
```

Where DT is name of the data.frame and ColName is the column name. There is only 1 column named ColName, where are all the data as seen.

How to extract the whole row with only partial search parameter?

Comment: it seems your data is in a strange format.  Any reason you want to preserve it as such, or is it better to clean it out first?

Comment: yes, strange format indeed!Long story.It is from scraping certain document. Certainly I would be open to cleaning etc. but that would bring me explaining the "Long story".No one wants this :)

Comment: It is possible that somewhere in your script, you have one two many calls to `list` something like:  `DT[i=.., j=list(list(..))]`.  It might be worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way your data is currently stored, the best option is to use `grepl` as in:

```
 DT[grepl("Tangible assets", V1)]
 # where V1 is the name of the column you are searching through
```

Comment: Thanks.One more thing.How to include more searching param. Like: c("Tangible assets","Investments")?

Comment: I have tried looping through a list("Tangible assets","Investments") but bit messy.

Comment: have a look at `?Regex`. The easiest option would be to use `"|"` as in:  `grepl("Tangible assets|Monty Python|Holy Grail", V1)`